# Can I use the Intel C++ compiler with biicode?

Tags: icc, biicode

biicode is a dependency management system for C++. I use the Intel C++ compiler (ICC), rather than gcc. Is it possible to use biicode, but continue to use ICC for building my project and dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As biicode uses the CMake build system, it should be possible just indicating CMake that you want to use that compiler. Depending on the platform it can be done differently. You can find info about setting different compilers [here](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_do_I_use_a_different_compiler.3F)

E.g. in Linux, it could be enough to define environment variables:

```
CC=icc
CXX=icc 
bii build
```

You can pass variables and options to cmake project configuration with the command bii configure, exactly as they would be passed to cmake, e.g. the generator:

```
bii configure -G "Visual Studio 12" -DMY_OPTION="myvalue"
```

So you could try something like:

```
bii configure -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=icc
```

In win with VS, you might need to set the toolset, this can be done with something like this in your CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET "Intel C++ Compiler XE 14.0" CACHE STRING "Platform Toolset" FORCE)
```

Though in general, specific configuration of compilers in the CMakeLists should be avoided and setting the environment via env or variables is preferred.